# Clever JavaScript to bypass eval method

Tags: javascript, malware

```
[]["constructor"]["constructor"](<string representing JavaScript code>)()
```

> In JavaScript the "constructor" property returns the prototype of an object. In this case the prototype of [] is the Array class. Accessing the "constructor" property of the Array class returns the Function object. The constructor of Function object then returns a function and the body of that function is the last parameter, which is passed to the constructor. This results in the creation of a function that uses the provided string as the function's body (i.e. code), which is then instantly executed.

As stated in the paragraph above from: https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Angler-Exploit-Kit-%E2%80%93-Gunning-For-the-Top-Spot/?page=1&year=0&month=0

The above line of code was used to execute obfuscated JavaScript code without using the 'eval' method. After reading this paragraph, I can't quite grasp this clever line of code. Can anyone explain what is actually happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the *constructor* of an *Array instance* is obviously `Array`:

```
[].constructor === Array
```

and further, the constructor of `Array` is `Function`:

```
[].constructor.constructor === Array.constructor === Function
```

Now in JavaScript, `Function(source)` returns a function instance whose source is given by the parameter. For example:

```
Function("alert(1337)");
```

will create (and is analogous to):

```
function() {
    alert(1337);
}
```

Your code will instantiate such a function and immediately call it with `()`. And that's exactly how `eval` behaves.

So, if it helps, you could reduce your code example to:

```
Function(source)();
```